# react-datepicker input width will not adjust to 100%

Tags: css, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am attempting to adjust the width of the react-datepicker input box and surprisingly have found little information out there and am unable to effect its width.  I would just like to make the input width 100% of its containing div.

#### Expected behavior

The width should expand to the width of its parent container.

#### My react-datepicker

```
<div className="myContainer">
  <DatePicker
    className="myDatePicker"
    fixedHeight
    readOnly={true}
    isClearable={false}
    placeholderText="End date"
    selected={this.props.defaultValue}
    onChange={(date) => this.props.handleDateChange(date)}
  />
</div>
```

#### Expected behavior

The following should result in the `myDatePicker` being the same width as the parent `myContainer`, but the width remains unchanged.

```
.myContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.myDatePicker {   
  width: 100%;  // note: if I change this value to a fixed value (such as 500px) then the width is effected
}
```

#### Closest Alternative attempt

The closest attempt was this, but it effects the width of the popup as well, causing it to stretch beyond the length of the entire screen, so this does not work as a solution either:

```
.myContainer div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

#### Actual behavior

The date picker remains the same length, unless a specific px value is set for the width.

**Does anyone understand how to set the input width to 100% for react-datepicker?**

---

**EDIT**
I believe the reason it does not work like a typical `input` field is because `react-datepicker` is an `input` that is embedded deeper inside other divs that have their own styling (or lackthereof)
[image]

**EDIT #2:** Here is a codepen showing the issue - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjxENG

Comment: Using styles to override styles will required `!important`. Try `width: 100% !important;`

Comment: <DatePicker wrapperClassName="w-full" />

TAILWIND use that

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it thanks to Rbar's answer.

Wrap your DatePicker component with a custom container. Then assign the width to that container and its children like below:

```
import "./customDatePickerWidth.css";

<div className="customDatePickerWidth">
   <DatePicker dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</div>
```

Inside the customDatePickerWidth.css:

```
.customDatePickerWidth, 
.customDatePickerWidth > div.react-datepicker-wrapper, 
.customDatePickerWidth > div > div.react-datepicker__input-container
.customDatePickerWidth > div > div.react-datepicker__input-container input {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @Ilyas! agreed. great solution.  It took me a few days to have a moment test out myself , but I just tried this out and like this better than my solution – simple, shareable, and solves the issue of needing to modify `node_modules`.  Great use of CSS!  Suggested just one edit, which is that it should make sure the `input` is set to `width: 100%` as well

Comment: Almost 2 years have passed and it is still a thing. Positioning Autocomplete, Datepicker and simple TextField in a row was the biggest challenge for me so far.. React, redux, async Thunks? Nah, just how put this damn DatePicker where I want.. that was the tricky part..

Answer (score 15):

I also stumbled into this issue as well. To solve this, there is a property that you can add directly to the DatePicker component which is the "wrapperClassName" and this property will allow us to directly apply classes to the "react-datepicker-wrapper".

Example:

```
<DatePicker wrapperClassName="datepicker" />
```

and then

```
.datepicker {
    width: 100%;
}
```

or if you are using tailwindcss, just directly apply

```
<DatePicker wrapperClassName="w-full" />
```

Note: This will only make the wrapper to be full width, therefore you will also need to apply "width: 100%" on the datepicker component if you want the input field to occupy full width as well.

Comment: nice tailwind implementation there thanks

Comment: wrapperClassName works, thanks!. Wondering its not on their documentation.

Comment: wow amazing that this isn't in their extensive (very) extensive documentation

Answer (score 9):

> **Simple solution**: Add this to your css file.

```
.react-datepicker__input-container {
  width: inherit;
}

.react-datepicker-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="react-datepicker-wrapper">
            <div class="react-datepicker__input-container">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used a wrapper div around the react date picker and used a specific css selector to make the wrapper divs react date picker applies around the input and the div I added to be width 100%

this is the css selector applied to a div which wraps the above snippet

```
.container > div, 
.container > div > div.react-datepicker-wrapper, 
.container > div > div > div.react-datepicker__input-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The result is the input box width stretches to 100% but the pop-out date picker box stays the same width

Answer (score 1):

```
//html file
  <div className="customDatePickerWidth">
              <DatePicker
                placeholderText="Select Schedule Date"
             />
  </div>

//css file    
.customDatePickerWidth, 
    .customDatePickerWidth > div.react-datepicker-wrapper, 
    .customDatePickerWidth > div > div.react-datepicker__input-container
    .customDatePickerWidth > div > div.react-datepicker__input-container input {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
    }
    .react-datepicker__input-container  {
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
      }
      .react-datepicker__input-container input {
        width: inherit;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .react-datepicker-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
      }
```

Comment: please add some explanations

Answer (score 1):

Gives the child (unnammed input) 100% while also give it's parent (__input-container) a block display.

```
.react-datepicker__input-container input {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the flex items from shrinking, set the flex shrink factor to 0:

.myContainer .myItem {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

```css
.myContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.myDatePicker {   
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <input class="myDatePicker">
</div>
```

The above snippet just works so there MUST be other code interfering with css or scaffolding.

Comment: should `myItem ` be `myDatePicker`?

Comment: Just tried the suggestion, but the width didn't change

Comment: I use this datepicker in every project. A working snippet would be appreciated to help you

Comment: What details are you looking for beyond what I have provided for "My react-datepicker" and the css under "Expected behavior"?  Happy to provide other but there is anything else to provide

Comment: I need a codepen o a jsfiddle with a renderable code. If this simple fix does not works (and I have a lot of project where it works) there should be some detail you've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Using styled-components

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
const DatePickerStyled = styled.div`
  /* STYLE FOR WITH */
  .react-datepicker-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```

encloses the component

```
<DatePickerStyled>
  <DatePicker dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</DatePickerStyled>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just passed a className to the component:

```
<DatePicker className='date-input-field' />
```

Here's how I set the width:

```
.date-input-field {
    max-width: 7rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

1. Remove all styling there is by default.
2. Introduce the width of 100%

My React datepicker:

```
 <div className="col-3">
          <DatePicker
            selected={st}
            onChange={(date: Date) => checkAndChangeStartTime(date)}
            showTimeSelect
            showTimeSelectOnly
            timeIntervals={5}
            timeCaption="Time"
            dateFormat="HH:mm"
            timeFormat="HH:mm"
          />
</div>
```

The CSS to make this option work:

```
.react-datepicker-wrapper>.react-datepicker__input-container input {
    all: unset !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

This forces the div to be 100% width, but requires you to start styling the element the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

just use:
`<DatePicker containerStyle={{width: '100%'}}/>`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

if you're using React and don't want to add more css rules you can use the `style` tag like so:

```
<>
  <style>
    {
      `input {
         width: 100%;
       }`
    }
  </style>
  <DatePicker
    selected={datetime}
    onChange={(date) => setDatetime(date)}
  />
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DatePicker is inline:

```
.react-datepicker,
.react-datepicker__month-container{
  width: 100%;
}
```