# How to extend React DatePicker pop-up once it's triggered to show?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

There is an annoying problem when I try to implement DatePicker form input in my simple frontend project. I've a page that displays a user form based on this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import './App.css' 
import { Container, FormGroup, Form, Button, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class CostLog extends Component {
    state = {  }
    render() { 
        return (
        <div>        
            <AppNavbar />
            <h2 style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '50px'}}>Cost overview</h2>
            <Container>
                <Form>
                <FormGroup>
                        <Label for='title'>Title</Label>
                        <Input className='input-cust' type='text' name='title' id='title' onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                    </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                        <Label for='title'>Category</Label>
                        <Input type='text' name='category' id='category' onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                        <Label for='date'>Date of Payment</Label>
                        <div className='datepicker-cust'>
                            <DatePicker className='datepicker-cust' onChange={this.inputHandler} value={this.state.date} />
                        </div>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                        <Label for='Place of Receipt Issuance'>Place of Invoicing</Label>
                        <Input type='text' name='place' id='place' onChange={this.inputHandler} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>                   
                        <Button color='info' type='submit'>Save</Button>{' '}
                        <Button color='secondary' tag={Link} to="/cat/total">Drop</Button>
                </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </Container>
            
        </div>  
        );
    }
}
 
export default CostLog;
```

Additively, case-related snippets inside of stylesheet file:

```
.datepicker-cust {   
   width: 500px;   
}

.react-datepicker-wrapper, .react-datepicker__input-container {
  display: block !important;
}
```

To be noted, I use `div` around `DatePicker` to make this field a bit broader. Whenever it's clicked, picker appears as a single column of days above the field, i.e. all days follow each other in vertical order, nothing like a normal calendar view I want to see. Using developer tool in Chrome, Mozilla, etc., I can suggest the problem takes its origin in zero width of Popper: it has a width equal to 0 and length 200.
This project I'm working on is just my first experience with React and its components. I found out what might be inconsistent here (supposing `Popper` has wrong size). This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710700/react-datepicker-input-width-will-not-adjust-to-100) for a topic-related issue doesn't work in my case: still the same vertical column of numbers instead of two-dimensional calendar pop-up. What needs to be changed in properties to display that as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I imported the `.css` file. 
`import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";`